# Ubuntu 20.04 Keyboard Not Working on Login Screen

Tags: keyboard, 20.04

Recently did a fresh install moving up LTS versions to 20.04. All went fine, but now at the login screen, the keyboard is non-responsive except for CAPS. Mouse works fine, but even with on-screen keyboard, I cannot login as the Enter key won't work.

I've booted into Recovery Mode and reinstalled xserver-xorg-input-all, but nothing has worked. I need some ideas. The keyboard works fine from the terminal in Recovery Mode.

Also tried plugging in a USB keyboard, but it does not work either.

I'm on a Dell Latitude E7440, fwiw. Had no previous issues on 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

I turned off Slow keys and Bounce Keys in the accessibility menu and all is well. I have no idea how that stuff was turned on...now I do: my kids.

Comment: Thank you! Somehow "Slow Keys" had gotten turned on for me too, and turning it off fixed it. I wouldn't have thought to look there!

Answer (score 0):

Settings-Region&Language-Input Sources-English(UK)

Choose your preferable keyboard layouts

Finally works for me!!